# Data.map is not a function API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I am trying to fetch API data but an error shows that data.map is not a function (in my case users.map). Please help me out.
I'm getting an error that map.data is undefined as a function? Looking at it I don't know what's not working .

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./bodypart.css";

const Bodypart = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  const getUsers = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
      "https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&api_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"
    );
    setUsers(await response.json());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="bodypart">
      <div className="bodypart__image">
        <div className="image">
          {users.map((curElem) => {
            return (
              <img
                src="https://www.thisislocallondon.co.uk/resources/images/12088462.jpg?display=1&htype=0&type=responsive-gallery"
                classname="bodypart__image"
                alt=""
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Bodypart;
```

API DATA is given below. I am unable to solve the problem by myself.

```
{
  "photos": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 10,
    "perpage": 100,
    "total": 1000,
    "photo": [
      {
        "id": "51398681312",
        "owner": "193303965@N08",
        "secret": "594df2ff71",
        "server": "65535",
        "farm": 66,
        "title": "",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "51398681362",
        "owner": "193209554@N03",
        "secret": "2de06284c5",
        "server": "65535",
        "farm": 66,
        "title": "SPIDERMAN NO WAY HOME RETOUCHES",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
      {
        "id": "51398682272",
        "owner": "193683913@N05",
        "secret": "d8258fa802",
        "server": "65535",
        "farm": 66,
        "title": "Türkiyədə FACİƏ: Sosial şəbəkə üçün video çəkən qız yüksəklikdən yerə çırpıldı - ANBAAN VİDEO",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
]
}
```

EDIT: Hello Friends , I got the answer instead of

```
          {users.map((curElem) => {
```

we will have to write

```
          {users.photos.photo.map((curElem) => {
```

EDIT 2

What should I write inside my console statement to return id of photo

```
{
  "photos": {
    "page": 1,
    "pages": 10,
    "perpage": 100,
    "total": 1000,
    "photo": [
      {
        "id": "51400489782",
        "owner": "144450638@N02",
        "secret": "2e68b6bb36",
        "server": "65535",
        "farm": 66,
        "title": "riki-shaham-wong-ping",
        "ispublic": 1,
        "isfriend": 0,
        "isfamily": 0
      },
```

Comment: Most solid would be probably to do something like  `users && typeof users.map === 'function' && users.map(yourMapFunc)` in your component.

Comment: Then you can open the  dev tools by pressing `F12` and open the network tab. You can inspect your request there and see what it's actually doing and if It's returning what you expect.

Comment: You should also add error handling to your async call. Otherwise, sooner or later you get unhandled rejection error or similar issues.

Comment: The return value is not an array. It's a user list either.

Comment: Its an object not an array. Its hard to read when formatted like this. Looks almost invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly your API call is returning undefined or something of that nature, which sets the `users` to `undefined`. Then when you use in later, you can't call map on undefined, which is the error you are getting.

You must first verify why that's happening and put some defaults so you don't run into run time exceptions.

```js
setUsers((await response.json()) ?? []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your fetch part inside `getUsers`. I copied the API address and got this error.

```
{"stat":"fail","code":100,"message":"Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)"}
```

You can update your funtion as follow.

```
 const response = await fetch(
      ...url
    );
 const data = response.json()

 if(Array.isArray(data))
    setUsers(data);
```

Comment: Because you don't have the API key, OP probably didn't share the real one.

Comment: Maybe. In that case, I would like to suggest copy the url, open the browser and paste it there to test the result by himeself.

Comment: This doesnt look like an API key `XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX`. Best is to change the code to handle possible fault responses. You never know when API server goes down. Afterwards, checking why it's not giving the proper response.

Comment: API is working fine. I purposely wrote "XXX" there.

Comment: Never mind. Whatever, did you try the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a `console.log(users)` somewhere in that component to see what `fetch` is returning from flickr. It may be an object that you need to extract an array property from.

Then check the browser developer tools console. You should see two console outputs before the type error; an empty array from the first rendering `[]` and the response from the fetch call during the second rendering.

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
console.log('Users: ', users);
```